# Build URL from Form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, url

I'm trying to build a url from a form.

The form has 3 fields and my idea is to look at the url when the user clicks the search button.

How could I do this?

Thanks you su much!!!

Comment: Please elaborate ! what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the form to use the GET method.

```
<form method="GET">
   <input type="text" name="foo" />
   <input type="text" name="bar" />
   <input type="submit" name="search" />
</form>
```

Then you can extract the values like this:

```
$_GET['foo'];
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! Only one more question... i dont like the construction of the url by GET: "?provincia=Alava&poblacion=Todas&aseguradora=Todas" How i can rewrite this one for "/provincia=Alava/poblacon=Todas" and hidden "aseguradora=Todas"?

Comment: If you want to alter the way the URL is displayed, then you should look into `mod_rewrite` in your `.htaccess`. Here's a link to got you started: [link](http://www.branded3.com/blogs/htaccess-mod_rewrite-ultimate-guide/)